# Is it possible to execute a left shift in a single clock pulse?

Tags: cpu, alu

I am currently designing my own 16 bit CPU and want to have a logic left shift instruction. I can make it shift only 1 position easily, but I want it to shift it b positions. Is that possible in a single clock pulse (or a constant number of clock pulses).

Example (using 4 bits):

Input A: 0011

Input B: 0010

Desired output: 1100

Comment: This is usually achieved with a barrel shifter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter

Comment: @PeterSmith. Vote to close if no reply from OP. Vote to close has been denied once.

Comment: I will give it until the morning for a response from OP.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! Close the question if you want, I got everything I need.